# LibGDX importing TMX files

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tiled, tmx

Ive been learning to code games in java and libgdx. My most hated part of any language Ive attempted is the Level Editor (.TMX , tiled) parsing. The Github for libgdx says there is a helpful class made for this which Ive been trying to follow the instructions but Im stuck.

Basically if I comment out the following line of code, the app runs fine but of course without any level elements included. When I have this line in code it crashes my phone instantly whilst loading app:

```
TiledMap map

public Level(OrthographicCamera camera) {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("level1.tmx"); /// THIS LINE CRASHES IT
}
```

I have checked the file 'level1.tmx' definitely exists in my 'assets' folder inside the Android folders of the game hierarchy.

If you do need the rest of my code Im happy to put it up but there is lots of garbage there not related to the problem. Thanks for any help

EDIT: One thing i think it may be is the type of file Im making in Tiled Editor. (ie. I chose zlib compression) other options were XML CSV and i think gzip

- ANOTHER EDIT -- i managed to view an error message at the bottom of Android Studio saying unable to load file "....tiles-brown.png" -- I was unaware I had to load those textures, the two tiles png files used are also in the assets folder anyway already but it says Couldn't Load on the errors. PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to load the textures yourself. The loader will load all referenced textures for you, but you will have to put them in your assets folder at the same location which was used when creating the map with TilEd. Since you didn't do that right, you get the exception.

A good way to do this is creating a folder `levels` and a folder `textures` in your `assets` directory. Put your .tmx files in `levels` and the tilesets in `textures`. Now when you import a tileset from TilEd, it will be referenced as `../textures/tileset.png`. To make sure this is correct, you can check the .tmx file. Do not use absolute file paths!

Comment: A combination of both answers helped me fix this. Ive awarded answer to Noone as he was faster. A massive thank u is owed to George too for his help, but the clear explanation regarding how to reference the filepaths and names is reason this answer helped most

Answer (score 1):

If your error is "unable to load file "....tiles-brown.png" then go to the folder in windows where you've stored the .tmx map. Right click and open in notepad. There you will see a reference path for each asset used on top of the file. Make sure the asset exists in the specified path in your project. If it doesn't or is different change it to where you store the assets for this map. Then save and refresh the android project. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi there thank for this answer it helped me solve it (in combination of noones answer below also). Basically I had made several tmx files with assets directly from my assets folder, however the internal of the tmx said images were at;  ".../Users/Myname/Documents/Etc/ETc/Etc/Gamename/Assets etc. By employing Noones foldering conventions and making new TMX it just says "../textures/tiles-green.png" , which sits inside the Assets folder. Just thought I'd type this to help just in case someone gets same problem that I did.